# Laravel join query with json data

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have products id in json format in sales table.
Now i want to fetch data and need to join with products table to get product details with it such as product name, product image,etc

Here is the sample data for sales table and orders column

```
[{"pcode":"R1160","qty":1,"price":"270","default_shipping":30},
{"pcode":"R1112","qty":1,"price":"250","default_shipping":30}]
```

Now i want to join query with products table and want all products details

Comment: The DB data is in JSON, or at the PHP level you're generating it as JSON?

Comment: Also provide database detail. MYSQL or something else??

Comment: database column contain json value

Comment: right now the database is on local...so cant share that

Comment: please post the structure of your product and other tables which you want to join. Also, are you getting any error ?

Comment: please tell me ...how can i share that

Comment: @ManishArora you use mysql??

Comment: sales.sql
http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/esEGZVQn/file.html
products.sql
http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/GZ2nL06e/file.html

Comment: these both links contain sample data with table stucture

Comment: Guys...solved now.

Comment: You have to mysql 5.7 or higher to use JSON function in query. Or else you have to manually get first product id from sale table then select products detail from products table no join possible in your case.